# Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at big_adder.vhd(24) near text ""; expecting ")", or ","

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm getting this error on quartus about a syntax error, but I cannot find it.

The program is a generic adder for 8 bits.

```
     LIBRARY ieee;
     USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    
     ENTITY big_adder IS
     PORT (a, b: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
     cin: IN STD_LOGIC;
     sum: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
     cout: OUT STD_LOGIC);
     END big_adder;
    
     ARCHITECTURE big_adder OF big_adder IS
     SIGNAL carry: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 DOWNTO 0);
    
     COMPONENT carry_lookahead_adder IS
     PORT (a, b: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
     cin: IN STD_LOGIC;
     sum: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
     cout: OUT STD_LOGIC);
     END COMPONENT;
    
     BEGIN
     carry(0) <= cin;
     gen_adder: FOR i IN 1 TO 8 GENERATE
        adder: carry_lookahead_adder PORT MAP(a(4*i–1 DOWNTO 4*i–4), b(4*i–1 DOWNTO 4*i–4), carry(i–1), sum(4*i–1 DOWNTO 4*i–4), carry(i));
     END GENERATE;
     cout <= carry(8);
     END big_adder;big_adder;
```

Comment: This would have been the example to make the rule to provide complete error messages. The [24th line contains non-iso8859-1 characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UC5O.jpg). These can occur when copy and pasting from non-ASCII based locale here from a publication from all appearances. You can see from the hex character dump there's issue with the minus signs. This in addition to the extraneous `big_adder;`  noted by ttobsen. Fix all the errors and the code analyzes (compiles).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks valid, except of the last line

```
     END big_adder;big_adder;
```

You have to remove one of the "big_adder;".

One personal hint: You should train yourself to write clean code from day 1!

Comment: Neither you nor the OP provided a complete list of error messages. There are non-is08859-1 characters in the line with the port map.